# What is the canonical range of speed a podracer might achieve?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

In *Star Wars - Episode I: The Phantom Menace*, we are introduced to the sport of Galactic Podracing. These podracers are supposed to be capable of insane land speeds, but we aren't told in the movie (that I'm aware of) what those speeds are.

In the game, *Star Wars - Episode I: Racer* for N64, podracers are commonly depicted as going anywhere from 400 KPH to upwards of 1400 KPH on certain zero G tracks, and with top level engine components. The [Wikipedia article on levels of Star Wars canon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_canon#The_Holocron) is somewhat vague about whether or not these speeds are canonical, however. On one hand, background information from games is considered C canon, whereas statistics are N-canon. Are speeds statistics? I don't know.

---

**TL;DR**: What is the canonical speed of a podracer? Is there a better source than *Racer*? Are the speeds in *Racer* canonical?

Comment: 700 KPH from memory... (in the race during the phantom menace)

Comment: @als which scene is that in?

Comment: @Pureferret in the novel, I think.

Comment: Surely someone has gone frame-by-frame through TPM and measured the number of pod-racer-lengths per second, and then measured Qui-Gon-Jinns per pod-racer, and looked up Liam Neeson's height.  It's all quite straightforward, if very time-consuming.

Comment: The tracks towards the end of that game were just insane. Anyhow, I suppose anything but the first track hasn't any canonicity value.

Comment: if we could find the length fro mthe game (canon, right?) and the time form the film...success?

Comment: Only if you assume that every moment of the race was depicted.

Comment: Why do people want to close this? Wookiepedia is not a good site for canon, this question should not solicit debate or polling, and neither is it ambiguous, vague or overly broad! This is a good question!

Comment: I don't see any reason this should be closed.  And no one is commenting as to why they're VTCing.

Answer (score 4):

According to the *Episode I Incredible Cross Sections*, it lists Anakin's pod having a top speed of 947 kph and Sebulba's having a top speed of 829 kph. I don't know if that is considered acceptable canon, but Wookieepedia seems to treat that source as such.

Comment: I'd probably judge that at S Canon

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Absolutely_Everything_You_Need_to_Know) factbook, Anakin's racer was capable of a top speed of **947kph (588mph)**.

> Podracers must be small and light, with nerves of steel and super-fact
>   reflexes.
>
> 947kph - Maximum speed of Anakin's winning podracer in the Boonta Eve
>   Classic

This ties in nicely with the speeds referred to in the [Star Wars: Episode I Incredible Cross-Sections](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_I_Incredible_Cross-Sections) factbook

> **DATA FILE - SEBULBA'S PODRACER**
>   **Engine manufacturer/type:** Collor Pondrat Plug-F Mammoth racing engines, fitted with Split-X ram air/radiator intakes
>   **Engine length:** 7.47 m (24 ft)
>   **Max. speed:** 829 kph (515 mph)
>   **Max. repulsorlift altitude:** 85 m (275 ft)
>   **Fuel:** Tradium power fluid pressurized with quold runium, activated with ionized injectrine
>
> **DATA FILE - ANAKIN'S PODRACER**
>   **Engine manufacturer/type:** Radon-Ulzer 620C racing engines, modified heavily by Anakin Skywalker
>   **Engine length:** 7 m (23 ft)
>   **Max. speed: estimated 947 kph (588 mph)**
>   **Max. repulsorlift altitude:** 105 m (350 ft)
>   **Fuel:** Straight Tradium power fluid activated with injectrine, no additives

And the [Inside the Worlds of Star Wars: Episode I](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Inside_the_Worlds_of_Star_Wars:_Episode_I) factbook

[image]